# ROUNDUP? what does it do? in C++

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me what this does?

```
#define ROUNDUP(n,width) (((n) + (width) - 1) & ~unsigned((width) - 1))
```

Comment: If this is C++, you're better off using an inline function to achieve this than a macro.

Comment: For the typical reasons why macros are bad. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html

Comment: ie what does ROUNDUP(n, x++) do?  well, it increments x twice! etc.  inline functions don't have that problem.  Also, look at the answer from STingRaySC - macros can be passed anything.  Functions have types.  If ROUNDUP was a function, then STingRaySC's example wouldn't compile.  (Although I'm not sure it would compile as a macro either, but in general the typeless nature of macros is a problem).
Among other reasons.  MACROS are EVIL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Providing width is an even power of 2 (so 2,4,8,16,32 etc), it will return a number equal to or greater than n, which is a multiple of width, and which is the smallest value meeting that criteria.

So width = 16;  5->16, 7->16, 15->16, 16->16, 17->32, 18->32 etc.

*EDIT* I started out on providing an explanation of why this works as it does, as I sense that's really what the OP wants, but it turned into a rather convoluted story. If the OP is still confused, I'd suggest working through a few simple examples, say width = 16, n=15,16,17. Remember that & = bitwise AND, ~ = bitwise complement, and to use binary representation exclusively as you work through the examples.

Comment: Note that the width *must* be a power of two... there are some cases where roundup seems to work for other widths (roundup width 3 works for n <5 for example) but only in a few bizarre corner cases.

Comment: Cute tony :-) Since 2^(1.58496298..) = 3 (say), I think it is reasonable to add an extra qualifier to indicate that powers of 2 of that type are excluded. I think an "even power of two" is a common if colloquial way of doing that. Sorry for a pedantic reply to a humorous comment :-).

Comment: @Bill here I was thinking you were excluding 1 ;) since that makes the part `~unsigned((width) - 1)` equal to 0 and thus the whole result equal to 0.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe No I think we can include 1, because the mask isn't then 0, it's ~0 (complement of 0, i.e. all 1s) and the macro is thus a no-op, i.e. n->n, which is as you'd expect (round up to the nearest multiple of 1 = do nothing).

Comment: You're right I had the orders of the operators in my head mixed up. It's when `width = 0` that what I said happens.

Answer (score 2):

It rounds n up to the next 'width' - but I think width needs to be a power of 2.

For example width == 8, n = 5:

(5 + 8 - 1) & ~(7)
= 12 & ~7
= 8

So 5 rounds to 8.  Anything 1 - 8 rounds to 8. 9 to 16 rounds to 16.  Etc. (0 rounds to 0)

Answer (score 2):

It defines a macro called `ROUNDUP` which takes two parameters, `n` and `width`, and returns the value `(n + width - 1) & ~unsigned(width - 1)`.

:)

Try this if you think you know what it does:

```
std::string s("WTF");
std::complex<double> c(-11,5);
ROUNDUP(s, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work in `C` because of the `unsigned`.  Here is what is does, as long as `width` is confined to powers of 2:

```
 n width ROUNDUP(n,width)
----------------
 0   4    0
 1   4    4
 2   4    4
 3   4    4
 4   4    4
 5   4    8
 6   4    8
 7   4    8
 8   4    8
 9   4    12
10   4    12
11   4    12
12   4    12
13   4    16
14   4    16
15   4    16
16   4    16
17   4    20
18   4    20
19   4    20
```